# How to prevent a file from being opened while it's being written to by another script python

Tags: python, json, file-io

I have one python script that:

1. - gets a JSON API every minute
2. - modifies the JSON object
3. - opens a local JSON file in write mode
4. - deletes the previous contents
5. - dumps the new modified JSON object onto the same file.

I have another script that then reads from that file and uses it to search for a specific value dependent on a key provided by user input from the frontend.

I am trying to prevent the unlikely, but plausible, scenario whereby the script that reads from the local JSON tries to open it for reading while it is being written to (or does not exist).

```py
try:
     with open('gtfsrProcessing/gtfsrDict_test.json','w') as updateDict:
                
           json.dump(restructured_dict,updateDict, indent=4)
```

Above is the code that dumps the JSON object to the file.

```py
if os.path.exists("gtfsrProcessing/gtfsrDict_test.json"):

        with open('gtfsrProcessing/gtfsrDict_test.json', 'r') as openFeed:
  
    
            gtfsrDict = json.load(openFeed)

        return gtfsrDict
```

And here is the code from the script that reads in the JSON file.

I was thinking of using the condition of  "if os.path.exists("path/to/file")."

My logic is that if I open the file in "w" mode in the script that writes to the file, the existing file will be deleted. However, I am unclear as to whether that deletes the file or just truncates the contents.

Also, it might not solve my problem as if the file is being written to, it must exist? Therefore it is still susceptible to being read before the update has been completed. Any decent solutions to this problem?

Comment: why in the same file, you cant add a timestamp at the end and delete the old one ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you add a little more detail please?

Comment: i understand that u collect a json every minute write it in a file, and read the latest one, so you can write a new json file (with different name) each time, and when u read the latest you delete the old ones which aren't used anymore

Comment: but how will the script that reads the file know the name of the latest file if it is changing

Comment: by its creation date: ```import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*') # * means all if need specific format then *.csv
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)```